# Advertisement not displaying on YouTube videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, adsense, ads, advertisement-server

I have created a youtube channel and uploaded a video created by me on my channel.

The issue is Advertisements are not displaying when someone playing or viewing my video.

What might be the issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ads dont automatically show on your uploaded Youtube videos. You have to [monetize them first](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/94522?hl=en).

```
1. Go to your Video Manager.
2. Next to the video you want to enable ads for, click Edit or the monetization icon .
3. Select the Monetization tab.
4. Select Monetize my video.
5. Select what ad formats you want to turn on for the video. Each type of ad format notes what devices it will appear on and includes an illustration of the ad placement.
6. Click Save changes.
```

**NOTE:**

> By turning on ads for videos on YouTube, you confirm that you have all
>   the necessary rights to the visual and audio elements of those videos.
>   You may be asked to submit information proving that you own all
>   necessary commercial use rights to any or all content in your video.

Comment: from where to go to Video Manager